# A good way to manage JLists in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have been using this framework for quite some time now, and I figured I should check and make sure that this is a good idea before implementing it into the large-scale Swing application I am working on now.

I have two interfaces that are at the root of my system:

```
public interface Colorable {
    Color getColor();
}

public interface Listable {
    String getListDisplay();
}
```

Then whenever I create a new `JList`, I create a new `ListRenderer`:

```
private class ListRenderer
            extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            if (!(value instanceof Listable)) {
                return this;
            }
            if (value instanceof Colorable) {
                Color c = ((Colorable) value).getColor();
                if (c != null) {
                    setForeground(c);
                }
            }
            Listable listable = (Listable) value;
            setText(listable.getListDisplay());
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Is this a good way to manage `JLists`?

Comment: Seems like a question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's a approach and a common one.  Another might be to create some kind "chained" renderer which you could chain together to change certain properties of the renderer more easily, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common and accepted method of handling this situation.